# R optim(): unexpected behavior when working with parent environments

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the function `fn()` which stores the most recent input `x` and its return value `ret <- x^2` in the parent environment.

```
makeFn <- function(){
    xx <- ret <- NA
    fn <- function(x){
       if(!is.na(xx) && x==xx){
           cat("x=", xx, ", ret=", ret, " (memory)", fill=TRUE, sep="")
           return(ret)
       }
       xx <<- x; ret <<- sum(x^2)
       cat("x=", xx, ", ret=", ret, " (calculate)", fill=TRUE, sep="")
       ret
    }
    fn
}
fn <- makeFn()
```

`fn()` only does the calculation when a different input value is provided. Otherwise, it reads `ret` from the parent environment.

```
fn(2)
# x=2, ret=4 (calculate)
# [1] 4
fn(3)
# x=3, ret=9 (calculate)
# [1] 9
fn(3)
# x=3, ret=9 (memory)
# [1] 9
```

When plugin `fn()` into `optim()` to find its minimum, the following unexpected behavior results:

```
optim(par=10, f=fn, method="L-BFGS-B")
# x=10, ret=100 (calculate)
# x=10.001, ret=100.02 (calculate)
# x=9.999, ret=100.02 (memory)
# $par
# [1] 10
# 
# $value
# [1] 100
#
# (...)
```

**Is this a bug? How can this happen?**

Even when using the C-API of R, I have a hard time to imagine how this behavior can be achieved. Any ideas?

---

**Note:**

- works:

  ```
  library("optimParallel") # (parallel) wrapper to optim(method="L-BFGS-B")
  cl <- makeCluster(2); setDefaultCluster(cl)
  optimParallel(par=10, f=fn)
  ```
- works:

  ```
  optimize(f=fn, interval=c(-10, 10))
  ```
- works:

  ```
  optim(par=10, fn=fn)
  ```
- fails:

  ```
  optim(par=10, fn=fn, method="BFGS")
  ```
- works:

  ```
  library("lbfgs"); library("numDeriv")
  lbfgs(call_eval=fn, call_grad=function(x) grad(func=fn, x=x), vars=10)
  ```
- works:

  ```
  library("memoise")
  fn_mem <- memoise(function(x) x^2)
  optim(par=10, f=fn_mem, method="L-BFGS-B")
  ```
- Tested with R version 3.5.0.

Comment: I'd send the example to the R-devel list (https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is happening because the memory address of `x` is *not* updated when it is modified on the third iteration of the optimization algorithm under the "BFGS" or "L-BFGS-B" method, as it should.

Instead, the memory address of `x` is kept the same as the memory address of `xx` at the third iteration, and this makes `xx` be updated to the value of `x` before the `fn` function runs for the third time, thus making the function return the "memory" value of `ret`.

You can verify this by yourself if you run the following code that retrieves the memory address of `x` and `xx` inside `fn()` using the `address()` function of the [envnames](https://cran.r-project.org/package=envnames) or [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/package=data.table) package:

```
library(envnames)

makeFn <- function(){
  xx <- ret <- NA
  fn <- function(x){
    cat("\nAddress of x and xx at start of fn:\n")
    cat("address(x):", address(x), "\n")
    cat("address(xx):", address(xx), "\n")
    if(!is.na(xx) && x==xx){
      cat("x=", xx, ", ret=", ret, " (memory)", fill=TRUE, sep="")
      return(ret)
    }
    xx <<- x; ret <<- sum(x^2)
    cat("x=", xx, ", ret=", ret, " (calculate)", fill=TRUE, sep="")
    ret
  }
  fn
}

fn <- makeFn()

# Run the optimization process
optim(par=0.1, fn=fn, method="L-BFGS-B")
```

whose partial output (assuming no optimization run was done prior to running this code snippet) would be similar to the following:

```
Address of x and xx at start of fn:
address(x): 0000000013C89DA8 
address(xx): 00000000192182D0 
x=0.1, ret=0.010201 (calculate)

Address of x and xx at start of fn:
address(x): 0000000013C8A160 
address(xx): 00000000192182D0 
x=0.101, ret=0.010201 (calculate)

Address of x and xx at start of fn:
address(x): 0000000013C8A160 
address(xx): 0000000013C8A160 
x=0.099, ret=0.010201 (memory)
```

This problem does *not* happen with other optimization methods available in `optim()`, such as the default one.

Note: As mentioned, the `data.table` package can also be used to retrieve the memory address of objects, but here I am taking the opportunity to promote my recently released package [envnames](https://cran.r-project.org/package=envnames) (which, other than retrieving an object's memory address, it also retrieves user-defined environment names from their memory address --among other things)

Comment: A good idea to track the memory addresses. - I think the problem occurs with both the "BFGS" and the  "L-BFGS-B" methods. I will probably make a bug report to CRAN soon.

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs with both methods "BFGS" and "L-BFGS-B".